# Get a PNG file from a Flutter Widget without drawing to the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a game a bit like Wordle, and I want to add a share capability much like Wordle does. I have a flag on my game grid widget which allows me to render the normal displayed version, or a special version for sharing. I'd like to use the widget to get a PNG file (or PNG byte data). I'd prefer to not actually draw this to the screen, just render it to some framebuffer and convert to PNG, although rendering to the screen is okay if the alternative is not possible. Looking through the docs, its not obvious whether what I am trying to do is possible or even makes sense (it seems I probably have to get the widget instantiated as an element and then get a render object, which seems to imply having to put it in my layout and draw it to the display), but maybe I am missing something. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### You might want to look at flutter's [`screenshot`](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package.

> A simple package to capture widgets as Images. Now you can also capture the widgets that are not rendered on the screen!

##### 1. Create Instance of Screenshot Controller

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Uint8List _imageFile;

  //Create an instance of ScreenshotController
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController(); 

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  ...
}
```

##### 2. Wrap the widget that you want to capture inside Screenshot Widget. Assign the controller to screenshotController that you have created earlier

```
Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: Text("This text will be captured as image"),
),
```

##### 3. Take the screenshot by calling capture method. This will return a Uint8List

```
screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) {
    //Capture Done
    setState(() {
        _imageFile = image;
    });
}).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
});
```

---

##### Extra: Saving images to Specific Location

```
final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory ()).path; //from path_provide package
String fileName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
path = '$directory';

screenshotController.captureAndSave(
    path //set path where screenshot will be saved
    fileName:fileName 
);
```

#### Refer [this](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot/example) example

Answer (score 0):

I was once working on an app in which I needed something similar. After searching for a while I found a package named '[screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)'

This package lets you convert both visible or invisible widgets to an image.

Here is the sample code from their document

```
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  function createScreenshot(){
     screenshotController
       .captureFromWidget(Container(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 5.0),
           color: Colors.redAccent,
         ),
         child: Text("This is an invisible widget"),
       ),
     ).then((capturedImage) {
       // Here you will get image object
     });
  }
```